# sql integer values get truncated when updated

Tags: mysql, integer

I'm running this code:

```
CREATE TABLE fish (SELECT '5' as size)
```

So far so good, I get 5 as size.
But then:

```
UPDATE fish SET size = size *2
```

should return 10, but it returns 1 instead, thus cutting off the last digit. I assume this is done because sql only saves enought necessary room when tables are created this way. Does anyone know if there is a way to fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that column as integer then why you use Single Quotes...?

just try like below... it will work....

```
CREATE TABLE fish (SELECT 5 as size)

UPDATE fish SET size = size *2
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't notice that.Thanks so much!

Comment: That's not the problem. You should take a look at @Klas answer. You may follow Pandian suggestion, but you'll still get 1 as returned value.

Comment: I'm aware that UPDATE returns the number of rows updates, I meant that this was the value I got when running 'SELECT * FROM fish'again. The real problem I had was with much bigger numbers, not 5 and 10

Answer (score 2):

`UPDATE` doesn't return the updated value, it returns the number of rows updated.

Comment: Exactly. running UPDATE fish SET size = size *2000 will still return 1 (if there's only one record in the table)